# Getting a comboBox to set the shown widget?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, qwidget, qcombobox

I'm making a GUI for a python program I've written and would like to have an area show a different `widget` depending on the choice of a `comboBox`.

This is a **MWE**:

[image: Main window]
I want the outlined area in this Main Window to show either the `TextWidget` or the `CalendarWidget`, depending on if the `comboBox` is set to `Option 1` or `Option 2`

[image: Text Widget] [image: Calendar Widget]

All the GUIs are built using Qt Designer and a python file uses `uic` to load them.

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui, uic

Main = "Main.ui"
MainUI, MainBase = uic.loadUiType(Main)
Text = "textwidget.ui"
TWidget, TBase = uic.loadUiType(Text)
Cal = "calendarwidget.ui"
CWidget, CBase = uic.loadUiType(Cal)

class OperatorGUI(MainBase, MainUI):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(OperatorGUI, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.comboBox.activated[str].connect(self.choose_widget)


    def choose_widget(self, choice):
        # Set the widget accorging to the choice
        #if choice == "Option 1":
        print choice


class TextWidget(TBase, TWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        # Something
        print "Text"

class CalendarWidget(CBase, CWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        # Something
        print "Calendar"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = OperatorGUI()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

If I use a `QtDockWidget` I can not place it where I want. I do not want it to be detachable or pop up in a separate window.

How can I solve this?

**Edit**

After some help from @eyllanesc the code now looks like this:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui, uic

Main = "Main.ui"
MainUI, MainBase = uic.loadUiType(Main)
Text = "textwidget.ui"
TWidget, TBase = uic.loadUiType(Text)
Cal = "calendarwidget.ui"
CWidget, CBase = uic.loadUiType(Cal)

class OperatorGUI(MainBase, MainUI):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(OperatorGUI, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.comboBox.activated[str].connect(self.choose_widget)

        self.ChangingWidget.setLayout(QtGui.QVBoxLayout())
        self.stacked = QtGui.QStackedWidget()
        self.ChangingWidget.layout().addWidget(self.stacked)
        self.textWidget = TextWidget()
        self.calendarWidget = CalendarWidget()
        self.stacked.addWidget(self.textWidget)
        self.stacked.addWidget(self.calendarWidget)


    def choose_widget(self, choice):
        # Set the widget accorging to the choice
        if choice == "Option 1":
            self.stacked.setCurrentWidget(self.textWidget)
        elif choice == "Option 2":
            self.stacked.setCurrentWidget(self.calendarWidget)
        print choice
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.show()


class TextWidget(TBase, TWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(TextWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setParent(parent)
        print "Text"

class CalendarWidget(CBase, CWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(CalendarWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setParent(parent)
        print "Calendar"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = OperatorGUI()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: remove self.setupUi(self) on choose_widget.

Comment: Done, still nothing showing though.

Comment: You have to call self.setupUi (self) inside the CalendarWidget and TextWidget classes.

Comment: Also `self.setParent(parent)` is not necessary since you have placed it through `super(TextWidget, self).__init__(parent)`

Comment: Thank you sooooooooo much! I've been stuck with this problem for days and not able to find any documentation for the `PyQt4` package that I could understand. You are a lifesaver and I wish I could give you more up-votes!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this task it is recommended to use [`QStackedWidget`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qstackedwidget.html), for this I assumed that the widget associated with that area can be accessed through self.widget:

```
class OperatorGUI(MainBase, MainUI):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(OperatorGUI, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.comboBox.activated[str].connect(self.choose_widget)

        self.widget.setLayout(QVBoxLayout())
        self.stacked = QtGui.QStackedWidget()
        self.widget.layout().addWidget(self.stacked)
        self.textWidget = TextWidget()
        self.calendarWidget = CalendarWidget()
        self.stacked.addWidget(self.textWidget)
        self.stacked.addWidget(self.calendarWidget)

    def choose_widget(self, choice):
        # Set the widget accorging to the choice
        if choice == "Option 1":
            self.stacked.setCurrentWidget(self.textWidget)
        elif choice == "Option 2":
            self.stacked.setCurrentWidget(self.calendarWidget)
```

Comment: @Kajsa  
In the first image there is a box below the QComboBox, what type is it and what is its name?

Comment: In the `.ui` it's a `QWidget` but I get the error `has no attribute 'addWidget'`. So I assume I need to use another type, which I can easily do as long as I understand which type to use.

Comment: Then I get the error `has no attribute 'addLayout'`.

Comment: @Kajsa It was a typo, I already corrected it, it must be `setLayout()` :P

Comment: @Kajsa If it worked, do not forget to mark it as correct, please. :P

Comment: Thank you. There is still something missing, I've made an edit with the current `.py` file.